# Is it possible to search for SAS youth tickets in external services?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, bookings, ita-matrix, sas

SAS has a youth ticketing scheme for people under 26. These tickets are part of fare class V and can be booked via their website.

I often use other services to look for flights, such as Skyscanner, Google Flights and ITA Matrix. Is it possible to use these tools to search for tickets in this specific fare bucket or can they only be searched and bought through the SAS website?

Comment: At least in matrix [via](https://www.travelcodex.com/2012/01/advanced-routing-language-in-ita/2/) `/f bc=v` in the advanced routing codes.

Comment: Let me correct my last comment, while in ITA Matrix you can search by fare class as indicated, I do not get it to display V class fares at all for dates when the SAS website indicates those as available, thus I assume they do not load that fare class bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I searched [Expertflyer](http://www.expertflyer.com) for Flight Availability the V class shows up and on the random date and city pair I have chosen (well, random but in a way that some flights have 0 in V) seems to show the same flights as SAS itself (I cropped the image because there are many, many flights on this city pair but it's enough to show the sameness):

[image]

[image]